# How do I change y-axis limits in seaborn histogram?

Tags: python, range, seaborn, histogram, axis

I have highly imbalanced raw data, which looks like:

```
df
Index Branch
1      10000
2        200
...
1000   1
...
10000  1
```

And if I run:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(df['Branch'], bins=1000)
```

The outcome looks like this:

[image]

Is there any chance to fix the maximum of the y-value in the visualization to 0.06? And to adjust the x-value to 1000 or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`seaborn` uses `matplotlib` under the hood so you can just

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(df['Branch'], bins=1000)
plt.ylim(0, 0.06)
```

Same for x-axis:

```
plt.xlim(0, 500)
```

Also the usual `plt.show()` to mute the undesired printout: `Out[60]: (0, 0.4)`

**EDIT :** Yes, it doesn't change the curve or the area under it. It only changes the boundaries of the "picture". I made the test, you can see below that the cumulative distribution curve is on the scale of the *data*, and not the *image*. If it did, the cumulative line (orange) would have reached 100% at the right of the image. I did this by adding `kde_kws={'cumulative':True}`.
[image]

Comment: And the "area under the curve" stays the same right? it does not change the value, only gives a snipchat of the data.