# How to change the y-axis ranges in a barplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

some time ago I posted a question how to change the [y-axis in a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325022/how-do-i-change-y-axis-limits-in-seaborn-histogram), it all worked out that time. Now I am working on a barplot, which looks like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.barplot(x="Hour", hue="Day", y="Änderung", data=df).set_title(a)
plt.ylim(-1, 6)
plt.show()
```

which should give me a barplot with fixed y-axis in the range of (-1,6), but somehow i get the error: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.

When I skip the code `plt.ylim(-1,6)` the output looks like this:

[image]

What is my error?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know for sure, but the error implies that Python thinks `plt.ylim` is a tuple and not a function. It looks like you did someting like `plt.ylim = (X,Y)` somewhere above the lines you are showing, which replaced the function `ylim()` with a tuple `(X,Y)`.

Usually, restarting the kernel should fix the issue